# step down 9V AC to 6V AC without transformer

Tags: ac

I've a circuit that I need to supply with an input voltage of 9V AC as well as an input voltage 0f 6V AC. Both are for a regulated power supply with one rail supplying 5V DC (from 9V AC) and the second rail 3.3V (from 6V AC). The load on the 3.3V DC rail is a crystal oscillator.

I've a transformer 220V to 9V AC, wasn't able to find a transformer that has two secondary windings for those exact voltages (yet) and I don't have space in the enclosure to mount a second transformer. Is there a way to derive 6V AC from the 9V AC secondary? What I've been able to find so far applies to stepping down DC voltages or did require a transformer.

TIA!

Comment: Do you really need AC or could you just bypass the onboard regulation and provide regulated 5VDC and 3.3VDC ? What you describe sounds like old-style power supply, before SMPS became prevalent.

Comment: Do you have a schematic diagram of this circuit that you can show us? Why does it need two AC inputs?

Comment: Quite likely your 6 V circuit will tolerate 9 V AC. Check the capacitor voltage rating, regulator input voltage range, regulator power handling, and you should be ok.

Comment: Or simply feed 5 V DC into the 6 V AC input, and short out or remove all the rectifier diodes as applicable. Check the voltage range of the 3.3 V regulator, it's likely to work from 5 V.

Comment: I don't have a schematic but can link to the manufacturer of the PCB [link]http://www.diyinhk.com/shop/audio-kits/46-17uv-ultralow-noise-dac-power-supply-regulator-33v55v-1ax4.html[/link]. The 5V rail would need 8-9V AC input and the 3.3V rail would need 5-6V AC.

Answer (score 1):

Work a little harder at finding a transformer with two secondary windings. This should not increase the size of the transformer much.

Alternatively use the one that you have with the 9VAC output. Rectify the 9VAC to DC and then use a voltage regulator to step that down to the needed 5VDC. This can be done with a cheap linear regulator such as a 7805 if the current load is very low. It the load current has any size to it at all the temperature created by power drop in the regulator can get prohibitive and so a better recommendation to convert the rectified voltage to 5V would be with a switching regulator. Once you have the regulated 5V then use a low drop out (LDO) linear regulator to further drop the 5V to 3.3V for the low current crystal oscillator load.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on the transformer but it's not easy due to where I live. The PSU PCB is already assembled and it's designed for those AC voltages unfortunately.

Comment: So if this is a repair operation as it now sounds like this becomes off subject here. On the other hand if it is a new design then bite the bullet and re-design the regulator board to use more modern technology than heavy transformers and linear regulators. It will be a lot more efficient and friendly to the planet.